# Building multiple bundles with r.js

Tags: build, module, requirejs, bundle, r.js

Hopefully a low-ball conceptual question. I'm having trouble understanding the `modules` option of [r.js build configs](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js).  I want to build multiple modules with nested dependencies with one r.js build config.

Say I have the following project structure:

```
+---build
+---src
    +---moduleOne
    |   +---moduleOne.js
    |   \---dependecyForModuleOne.js
    +---moduleTwo
    |   +---moduleOne.js
    |   \---dependecyForModuleTwo.js
    |---buildConfig.js
    |---devModuleConfig.js
    \---prodModuleConfig.js
```

`devModuleConfig` and `prodModuleConfig` are the dev and prod runtime configs, and `buildConfig.js` is the r.js build config.

Now, I can build moduleOne no problem using this config:

```
({
    "baseUrl": "./",

    "name": "moduleOne/moduleOne",
    "out": "../build/moduleOneBundle.js",

    mainConfigFile: 'devModuleConfig.js',
    optimize: 'none'
})
```

I end up with a bundle in build that I can run after specifying different paths in the build config:

```
+---build
    \---moduleOneBundle.js
```

I want to build two modules, so specify `moduleOne` using `modules` config option:

```
({
    "baseUrl": "./",
    modules: [
        {
            "name": "moduleOne/moduleOne",
            "out": "../build/moduleOne.js"
        }
    ],

    dir:"../build", //   <-- r.js says I need to add this.  why?

    mainConfigFile: 'devModuleConfig.js',
    optimize: 'none'
})
```

As well as the required `dir` option, I get all my configs in the `build` dir, but I did not specify them, and I do not get my bundled module, and I get a text file containing r.js build output.  In fact, `build` ends up looking exactly the same as `src`:

```
+---build
    +---moduleOne
    |   +---moduleOne.js
    |   \---dependecyForModuleOne.js
    +---moduleTwo
    |   +---moduleOne.js
    |   \---dependecyForModuleTwo.js
    |---build.txt
    |---buildConfig.js
    |---devModuleConfig.js
    \---prodModuleConfig.js
```

How do I configure multiple modules to build using one r.js config?  I've read the docs a few times and can't get my head around it.

You can see my project that contains all this here:  https://github.com/sennett/r.js-multiple-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying `modules`, r.js includes all files then optimizes ones based on the rules specified in `modules`.  `removeCombined: true` deletes modules from `build` that were combined into another module, and then manual deletion of the other files can be used to manually clean up any unwanted build artefacts.